# Sync MQTT attribute timestamp with observedAt

Tags: fiware

I have a sensor that publish their data at a MQTT topic. I have a variable called timestamp (in ISO format). How i can use the timestamp from it to set the observedAt that is send to the Context Broker (Orion-LD). In the case of http binding i can add the "t (timestamp): Timestamp of the measure. Will override the automatic IoTAgent timestamp (optional)" to the POST on the IOT agent?

Answer (score 0):

At least in current implementation of iotAgent a measure called “TimeInstant” plus a config with timestamp=true will behave like the ?t query param in the NGSIv2 northbound binding.

Probably it works in the same way for the NGSILD.